# angular-moment not working via dom injection

Tags: javascript, angularjs, momentjs, angular-moment

I have a page with angular-moment on it. Upon page rendering angular-moment is working.
Using

```
<span am-time-ago="message.time"></span>
```

But when I append new html.. it's not working

```
   var date = '<span am-time-ago=\"message.time\"></span>';
   angular.element('#here').append(date);
```

Did I missed something? Please help...

Thanks, Kurai

Comment: do you have a fiddle to play around?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML that is appended manually must be bound to a `$scope`.

To do this you inject and use the `$compile` service.

```
// Pass element or HTML string to `$compile` to get a link function
var linkFn = $compile('<span am-time-ago="message.time"></span>');

// Pass `$scope` to the link function to get an element bound with it
var element = linkFn($scope);

// Append the element
angular.element('#here').append(element);
```

It's often written like this:

```
var element = $compile('<span am-time-ago="message.time"></span>')($scope);
angular.element('#here').append(element);
```

*Note that if you must add HTML manually like this and want to follow the best practices of Angular, it should be done from a directive.*